# Pandas Three Month Moving Average with nulls

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

I would like to calculated a 3 month moving average by team. The "catch" is that there are bye-weeks and summer vacations where we need to "skip" and do an average of the three months with data.

[image]

I was able to write this in SQL for my problem but I now need to re-write it in Python in order to automate the process. My Python is beginner and knowing how long it took me to figure this out in SQL, I am hoping someone can help me with what to look for as a similar question on Stack Overflow OR help me with some lines of code to start with?

I've pasted the dataset into [Google Sheets here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LqiczRXt0Um3MdGS8jx8JjEg03fiPcOeoMhjUNMQnpM/edit#gid=0) and below is an image of the dataset. The right most column (G) is the "correct answer" and column D is the "source" for the three month rolling value. Columns E and F were useful to me in figuring it out in SQL but are not in the dataset.

[image]

Comment: How do you know how much to extend by? Is each `__BYE__` and `__SUMMER VACATION__` "worth" one month extra?

Comment: No images please! Please see how to ask a pandas question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: @noah yes they are each worth one point...sorry if it was unclear.